# What is the philosophical position that a metaphysical debate is caused by different mental models?

Tags: metaphysics, kant, time, skepticism

I'm looking for authors, papers, and hopefully, the name of the philosophical position that I describe here. I've seen a couple of papers so I know that they exist, but I can't recall the authors or titles.

Here is an artifical example of the position: suppose philosophers F and R argue over the true nature of sets. F claims that sets are just special functions. A set of X is just a function mapping X to {True,False}. Any value that maps to True is in the set, and any value that maps to False is not. R claims that a set is just a 1-place relation. That is, there are 2-place relations such as "__ is larger than __", there are 3-place relations like "__ is between __ and __", and there are 1-place relations such as "__ is blue". The 1-place relations are called sets.

The position I am talking about would point out that F and R both believe the same things about functions, relations, and sets, their only dispute is which mental model to use in thinking about sets. This is not merely a verbal dispute. The sentences of one cannot be translated directly into the sentences of the other by simple changes in word meaning. There are genuine underlying differences in their mental models, but at the same time, they can both be right about everything *except* their claim that their own mental model is ontologically privileged, and there is no fact of the matter about which mental model is "correct". Things are what they are, independent of our mental models for thinking about them.

Here is a more concrete example: an eternalist says that all moments in time exist: the past exists, the future exists, and the present exists. Our consciousness just travels through this temporal dimension. A presentist says that the past no longer exists, the future does not yet exist, and only the present exists.

The position I am thinking of would say that the two philosophers  agree on practically everything to do with time except what mental model to use in thinking about time. The eternalist visualizes time as analogous to space. He imagines the whole of time laid out at once. The presentist imagines time to be a continuous progression of the past going out of existence and the future coming into existence. The position I am describing claims that the only substantive disagreement, is which mental model reflects reality, and that that disagreement is ill-posed and unresolvable.

This is not just a verbal dispute; there are real differences in their mental models, and they are both making different ontological claims, but the ontological claims are nothing more than "my mental model is real and yours is not". This position would say that such ontological claims are misguided because reality is not any mental model at all. Ontological claims can only be made within a mental model and they are trying to make a claim *about* a mental model.

This is more of a Kantian critique of metaphysics than a Humean, Wittgenstenian, or positivist critique. It doesn't deny that there is a real issue; rather, it rethinks what the real issue is. And it denies that we have the capacity to resolve it because we haven't the ability to access the reality behind our mental models.

Can anyone give me help in looking up this position? Since I don't even recall what it is called, I don't know what to search for.

Comment: It seems like it relates to how the Quantum Measurement Problem is treated by the physics community - the answers to the perceived problem are unfalsifiable by current or even proposed experiments, so currently differences of opinion on the issue are metaphysical. But like with time, that almost certainly will change

Comment: I'm pretty sure Wittgenstein dealt with this.

Comment: Wittgenstein was more of a skeptic about metaphysics, in other words, he is what I contrasted the position to.

Comment: Generally speaking, this sort of position is called *deflationism* (or even skepticism, with a qualifier), in this case, about temporal ontology. It is argued e.g. in [Lombard, Time for a Change: A Polemic against the Presentism–Eternalism Debate](https://www.academia.edu/8296421/Time_for_a_Change). For arguments against it see [Sider, Quantifiers and Temporal Ontology](http://tedsider.org/papers/quantifiers_and_temporal_ontology.pdf) and [Graziani-Orilia, Temporal ontology: tenselessness and quantification](https://www.academia.edu/46145383/Temporal_ontology_tenselessness_and_quantification).

Comment: You appear to be describing "ordinary Language Philosophy", which sought to dissolve supposed philosophic problems by declaring them just to be mistakes in the use of language.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_language_philosophy

Comment: @Dcleve, it's not the same. The only "mistake" this position alleges is the mistake that the two sides think their preferred model is uniquely true, that the alternative models cannot be true as well.

Comment: @DavidGudeman -- but is that not just one instance of the general Ordinary Language view?  That THIS dispute is a linguistic error, just as ALL philosophical debates are?

Comment: @Conifold, thanks for the references. However, I think I described the position badly. The temporal philosophy was just an example of what I meant. I've edited the question and added an artificial example that will hopefully make it clearer. I hope you will read the edited version and respond because you seem to be extremely well-read in philosophy.

Comment: @Dcleve, I think I described the problem badly. I've rewritten the question and added an artificial example in hopes of clarifying. I would appreciate it if you would read it again and respond.

Comment: If their models aren’t committing them to an actual ontology, but they are different models beyond disagreements in language, and their models can give the “same” answers (both could predict the same experimental outcomes or mathematical answers to equations, albeit in different methodologies), what comes to my mind is some form of structuralism.

Comment: This is still deflationism, semantic vs mental may affect its plausibility but not its nature. The difference in mental processing is not "meaningful" in a philosophically salient sense, it is a side issue, and this does make the dispute purely "verbal". In philosophy generally "language" is interpreted very broadly. But reducing it to mental does not get you to Kantian "ill-posed and unresolvable". We can surely transcend our mental models and resolve claims about them, Kant refers to much more fundamental "transcendental" structures of the intellect beyond the minutiae of mental processing.

Comment: will try again. I hate the feature that hitting then Enter key posts a comment.

Comment: @Conifold, a mental model is not a psychological process any more than a Kantian intuition is. A mental model is a conceptual framework by which we understand metaphysical issues, much like an intuition is the framework by which we perceive the physical world. Just as Kant argued that our cognition is limited by our  intuitions which are not identical to the noumenal world, so this position claims that our cognition of metaphysical topics is limited by our mental models of the metaphysical world. We have no direct access to the nature of time, only to a mental model of time.

Comment: What Kant has in mind is not a "conceptual framework" that we, or our descendants, can revise or replace, as was done many times. Not even if some aspects of it are psychologically or biologically wired. All of that is empirical psychology/anthropology to him. He means fundamental structures that define us as subjects, we'd have to become God to transcend *that*, as he hints. Only *then* do you get absolute irresolvability. Limitations of mental models, in contrast, are relative and historically transitory, how limiting they are is an empirical question, not an *a priori* one.

Comment: There is no legitimate perspective outside of possible (to us) experience. Kantian prohibition applies to *any* ontological dispute, so the position you describe would be vacuous. On the other hand, there is a perspective outside of our mental model. Namely that of a refined model that we may eventually adopt, and already have capacity for. We do not need ontological access to time for that, it is about a correct theory of *appearances*. And presentism/eternalism debate is potentially resolvable as such, we can't tell *a priori*. So if we mentalize Kant we do not get the desired outcome either

Comment: @Conifold, the position adds detail to Kant's epistemology. A mental model (a term I invented, BTW; I don't recall what the papers called it) is what happens when you try to go beyond a pure intuition. Kant would have said the metaphysician is simply incapable of discussing the nature of time at that level. This position begins with that premise and asks: "then what are the metaphysicians talking about?" They aren't talking about phenomena because our pure intuition of time doesn't distinguish between presentism and eternalism (if it did, there would be no debate). They aren't talking about

Comment: @Conifold: noumenon, because that is impossible, they aren't talking nonsense or fiction because what they say is often true and they aren't talking subjectively because the ideas can be communicated and shared. The conclusion is that there is something analogous to a pure intuition (which I call mental models) that frames their understanding. Mental models differ from pure intuitions in that there are several contrasting mental models, and that individuals can often switch between them, but they still limit cognition in that we have to pick one; we can't get past them.

Comment: For Kant, time  is a form of *our* intuition, and knowledge of it is certainly possible, it is what he calls [transcendental knowledge](http://philosophyreaders.blogspot.com/2019/10/kants-distinction-between-transcendent.html). But Kant aside, if switching and refining models is possible then we can surely get past them. They can impose no absolute limitations. What limitations they do impose are empirical and transient, but it never stopped us from having debates over such things that were eventually resolved. To summarize, such a position is not named because it is inconsistent.

Comment: @Conifold, I know what Kant says about time. The fact that you think you need to explain it to me suggests that we are failing to communicate. At  this point, I have given up hope that we can.

Comment: I'll try one last time. What I think you want is deflationism nice, acknowledging substantive disagreement in some way, putting a new perspective on it, rather than dismissing it as merely verbal. But the conclusion still is that the dispute should be set aside due to perennial inaccessibility of its subject matter. However, the very new perspective that you put on it gives it new air. Your perspective is that the dispute really is about mental models, not ontology. But then what does inaccessibility matter? It is now recast as a dispute about a better model of what *is* accessible.

Comment: I've been debating whether to respond to this because I don't want to turn this into a discussion, but I'll note that the point of the analysis, as I understood it, is that the opposed mental models are equivalent in how well they account for phenomena. There is no objective sense in which one is better than the other, nor any  reason to think that an objectively better one is possible.